# How to update a plotly graph with new data in Python?

Tags: python, graph, charts, plotly

I am using Chart Studio. How do I update my graph with new data, without losing previously uploaded data? I cannot upload everything all at once every time, because uploads are "limited to 524.288 KB". So I have to upload incrementally. Is this possible? By the way, fileopt='extend' does not work in the new version upgrade, but that is the type of functionality I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I did not discover how to extend traces however I did find out how to get around the upload limit. The method involves generating charts on github pages which can be used to create iframes, without file size limits. This is an effective workaround for me. More information here: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-plotly-visualization-and-embed-it-on-websites-517c1a78568b